# How to do custom search in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have one address table in that postcode column is there let me explain the scenarios
For example:- 523272 records are there

1. if i search with 5232 i don't want to get results.
2. if i search with 523272(Exact match) i need to get results.
3. if i search with 5232725656 Now also i need to fetch results related to 523272 records (starts equals to condition).

i tried for this one wildcard entries and length it's not working,can you help me to achieve this scenario.

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE postcode LIKE '%523272';
```

Comment: You have to use `LIKE` to match a pattern. `=` is exact match.

Comment: @Barmar it's my bad typo error i used like only

Comment: use like operator. for second scenario crop the text and search first 6 characters since you have 523272 records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reverse the condition. Append the wildcard to the column value, and match the search string against that pattern.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE '523272' LIKE CONCAT(postcode, '%')
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a738/2)

Note that this can't be indexed, so it will be slow on a large table.

Comment: it's not fetching results actually records are there

Answer (score 1):

You can try this I have tested all possible values and @post is a variable in which you can set your value

Ex :

```
set @post=523;

select * 
from address 
where @post like CONCAT('%',postcode,'%') or postcode like CONCAT('%',@post,'%')
        or  @post like CONCAT(postcode,'%') or postcode like CONCAT(@post,'%')
        or  @post like CONCAT('%',postcode) or postcode like CONCAT('%',@post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use Regex_Like operator along with Substring and RPAD. Following might work:

`SELECT * FROM WHERE REGEX_LIKE (postcode, concat(RPAD(SUBSTRING('SEARCHSTRING', 1, 6), 6, '?'), '.+'));`

```
if SEARCHSTRING = 5232, the regex expression becomes 5232??.+
if SEARCHSTRING = 523234, the regex expression becomes 523234.+
if SEARCHSTRING = 523234123, the regex expression becomes 523234.+
```